# Finding diagonal in 2D array and replacing with 0 above it

Tags: c#, diagonal

So the start is:

```
        Random r = new Random();
        int[,] mas = new int[4, 5];
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                mas[i, j] = r.Next(1, 10);
                Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i, j]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
```

Looks something like

```
4 3 5 6 2

3 5 6 7 4

2 3 4 5 5

2 3 4 5 6
```

What i i need is to get 0 above the diagonal.

```
4 0 0 0 0

3 5 0 0 0

2 3 4 0 0

2 3 4 5 0
```

This is what i've got so far, no what i need , but atleast got some diagonal and some 0's.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < mas.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                mas[i, j] = 0;
                Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i, j]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do everything in one go, you could do this:

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int[,] mas = new int[4, 5];
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mas.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            mas[i, j] = j > i ? 0 : r.Next(1, 10);
            Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i, j]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
```

Otherwise, your second section needs to be:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < mas.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            if(j > i) mas[i, j] = 0;
            Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i, j]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one  (inside the inner loop):

```
if(j > i ) mas[i, j] = 0; // column number > row number, above diagonal
```

or the (better) alternative  (inside the outer loop):

```
for (int j = i+1; j < mas.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    mas[i, j] = 0;
    Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i, j]);
}
```

Comment: And your 'better' alternative will never print `mas[0,0]`

Comment: @JRLambert I assumed this is about **setting** elements to 0, not printing them. since  `mas[0,0]` is on the diagonal it is not set to 0 and not printed (in the set-Loop). This needs an extra loop for printing, of course

Comment: Looking at his `for` loops, you can see that he is looping through each `i` and looping through each `j` in `i`. You an also see that he is **printing** out each `mas[i,j]`, regardless of if it is set to 0

Answer (score -1):

Using Linq

```
Random r = new Random();
            //int[,] mas = new int[4, 5];

            int[][] mas = new int[4][];


            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            {
                mas[i] = new int[5];

                for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    mas[i][j] = r.Next(1, 10);
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i][j]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
            {
                mas[i] = mas[i].Select((c, ind) =>
                {
                    if (ind > i)
                        c = 0;

                    return c;

                }).ToArray();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm not using Linq at the moment!
Learning from basics :)

Comment: @naathankz you're welcome, this one can be left here for future references (because I'm learning too!)