# Editting a 2D array with Linq and ForEach

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27530303/111110) in a Linqified way

"Finding diagonal in 2D array and replacing with 0 above it"

This is my Linqfied solution:

```
Random r = new Random();
        //int[,] mas = new int[4, 5];

        int[][] mas = new int[4][];


        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = new int[5];

            for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].Length; j++)
            {
                mas[i][j] = r.Next(1, 10);
                Console.Write("{0}\t", mas[i][j]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // my code starts here
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = mas[i].Select((c, ind) =>
            {
                if (ind > i)
                    c = 0;

                return c;

            }).ToArray();
        }
```

It works, but I want to get rid of the for-loop, then I did:

```
 mas.ToList().ForEach(m0 =>
            {
                m0 = m0.Select((c, ind) =>
                {
                    if (ind > k)
                        c = 0;

                    return c;

                }).ToArray();

                k++;
            });
```

Despite the inner elements `m0` get the desired values changed to zero in debug time, the `mas` 2D array don't get its values changed.

Comment: Well, of course not. You change the variable `m0` to some different value, but it doesn't get assigned back to the collection. That's why you can't really do that with a foreach loop.

Comment: Does the initial `mas.ToList()` work as expected?  I've never tried calling ToList() on a 2D array.

Comment: LINQ, as per the name (Language INtegrated 
*Query*) is a tool for writing *queries*.  A query allows you to create a new result set, it's not there for mutating an existing data set.  If you want to create the arrays and then mutate them, then you shouldn't be using LINQ at all.  If you want to use LINQ, use LINQ to *create the queries based on the results of the LINQ operations*.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the explanation, I wasn't unsure if ToList().ForEach was mutable or not

Comment: @Broken_Window That's not LINQ, and it is also accepting a method, which is no different than the LINQ method in this respect; parameters are passed by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq like so:

```
mas = mas
    .Select((a, i) => a.Select((c, j) => j > i ? 0 : c).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the parameter to the method, which is a copy of the value in your arrays.  Mutating that copy does not mutate the original array.

A proper LINQ-based solution to this problem would be to use LINQ operations such that the results of executing the query is your data set, rather than having the execution of the query mutate some other data set:

```
var random = new Random();
var query = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
    .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
        .Select(j => j > i ? 0 : random.Next(1, 10))
        .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```